# Weak formulation

Tags: estimation, fluid-dynamics

I am working on the couple of stokes and elastic equations and I want to find the weak formulation:

$$ ρ_1v_t +∇p−μ_1∇·(∇v+∇v^T)=ρ_1f_1\ \ \ \ \text{in}\ \ (0,T)×Ω_1,$$

$$ ∇ · v = 0 \ \ \ \text{in}\ \ \ \  (0, T ) × Ω_1,$$

$$v=0\ \ \ \text{on}\ \ \ (0,T)×Γ_1\ \ \text{and}\ \  v|_t=0 =v_0\ \ \ \text{in}\ \ \ \ Ω_1,$$

$$ρ_2u_{tt} −μ_2∇·(∇u+∇uT)−λ_2∇(∇·u)=ρ_2f_2 \ \ \  \text{in}\ \ \ (0,T)×Ω_2,$$

$$u=0\ \ \ \text{on}\ \ \ (0,T)×Γ_2,\ \ \ u|_t=u_0\ \ \ \text{in}\ \ \ Ω_2,\ \ \ u_t|_t =u_1\ \ \ \text{in}\ \ \ Ω_2,$$
Where $Ω_1$ and $Ω_2$ are the fluid and solid domains respectively.

We also have the following equalities on the interface $\Gamma_0$ : $$u_t=v$$ and $$μ_2(∇u+∇uT)·n_2 +λ_2(∇·u)n_2 =pn_1 −μ_1(∇v+∇vT)·n_1$$ where $n$ is the outward normal vector.

How can I follow from the last equation on $\Gamma_0$ to get the weak formula.

The free-divergence weak formulation I have to arrive to is:

$$\frac{d}{dt} ρ_1[v, η]_{Ω_1} + ρ_2[∂_tu, η]_{Ω_2} + a_1[v, η] + a_2[u, η]
=ρ_1[f_1,η]_{Ω_1} +ρ_2[f_2,η]_{Ω_2}$$
 $\forall η \in H^1_0$ with zero divergence

Where $[ .,. ]$ is $L^2(\Omega)$ inner product. 
$$a_1[u,v]=\frac{\mu_1}{2} \int_{(\Omega_1)}(∇u+∇uT):(∇v+∇vT)dΩ. \\a_2[u,v]=\frac{\mu_2}{2} \int_{(\Omega_2)}(∇u+∇uT):(∇v+∇vT)+\lambda_2 (∇.u ) (∇.v) dΩ$$

Comment: @CheeHan I have multiplied by a function in $H^1_0$ with zero divergence and integrated over $\Gamma_0$ but it becomes more complicated

Comment: @CheeHan I have edited my question, I wrote the equation I have to arrive to

Comment: You take the inner product in $L^2(\Omega_{1,2})$ and manipulate your terms make advantage of the fact that $div u=0$ it will simplify the computation

Comment: @karimaths check what I have written in the answer below, it is the same idea, isn’t it?

Comment: Yes it is and that is why i voted for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $\phi \in H^1_0(\Omega)$  such that  $div(\phi)=0$ where 
$\Omega = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$
 Multiplying the first and the second  equations by $\phi$ and integrating over $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ respectively, then adding the two equations we will obtain the weak formula written above(in the question) and since $\Gamma_0$ is a subset of $\Omega$ then we can incorporate the stress interface condition into the weak formulation.

This means we arrive to our result without needing derive the equation given on the interface.